# Alarm Clock that opens a webbrowser in python using Tkinter and displays time

Tags: python, tkinter, clock, alarm

I'm very new to Python, and was trying to figure out a way of making an alarm clock that could display time using Tkinter, and would open a url when the desired time was reached. The issue as far as I can tell is that the program skips the while loop, and so the url never opens. I know that it can be improved in a lot of ways, but for now I really just want to know how to get the url to open at the entered time.

```
from Tkinter import *
import time
import webbrowser

class App:
    def __init__(self,master):
        frame=Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.w=Label(frame,text="",bg="red")
        self.w.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.entry=Entry(frame)
        self.entry.pack(side=LEFT)


        self.Button1=Button(frame,text="Enter Hour Here",command=self.hour)
        self.Button1.pack(side=LEFT)


        self.entry2=Entry(frame)
        self.entry2.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.Button2=Button(frame,text="Enter Minute Here",command=self.minutes)
        self.Button2.pack(side=LEFT)




    def hour(self):
        None

    def minutes(self):
        self.update_time()

    def checktime(self):
        alarmminute=self.entry2.get()
        alarmhour=self.entry.get()
        j=0
        while j<1:
            if time.localtime().tm_hour==alarmhour and time.localtime().tm_min==alarmminute:
                webbrowser.open("google.com")
            else:
                j=j+1
        self.update_time()

    def update_time(self):
        now = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        self.w.config(text=now)
        root.after(1000, self.checktime)

root=Tk()
app=App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: actually, i just checked the while loop, and it looks like it's working. But, for some reason, when the localtime's hours and minutes are equal to the alarm time's hour and minutes, it's not entering the "if" statement.

Comment: nvm, figured it out, the entry wasnt being read as an integer for some reason.